# Get product attribute in cart in Magento2.2

Tags: cart, magento2.2, product-attribute, migration

I am migrating **Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2** and I need to know how to `display the Delivery Term attribute` that **each product has in the cart**.

Someone could help me?

because I've tried several options but I can not get any of them to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create `{MODULE_NAME}/etc/catalog_attributes.xml` with such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="custom_attribute"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Afterwards you can easily copy the file

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

under your theme directory

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

and then you can add the line to display the attribute `<?php echo $product->getCustomAttribute(); ?>`

Comment: This is my catalog_attributes.xml

In the default.phtml i¨ve tried getCustomAttribute(); ?> but it has no value. I also tried with: $_product = $block->getProduct(); $tiempoEnvio = $_product->getAttributeText('tiempo_envio');

But the same the attribute tiempo_envio has not value. Could you help me?

Comment: try this code
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tiempo_envio')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

Comment: Now it always returns me No instead of returning the delivery time of the product, for example 24-48 hours

Comment: The strange thing is that if I show the Sku for that product if it does well <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sku')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

Comment: Can you check in database attribute value instead or not instead?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, even on the product page is displayed correctly

Comment: It´s ok now, i was creating the catalogs_attributes.xml in the wrong directory , this is the correct pp/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/catalog_attributes.xml